# Semantic UI modules correctly styled but not responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I am quite new to JS and Jquery and I fear that I must have missed something fundamental to incur this error: none of the semantic modules I tried to include in the html and initiate with JS appears to be responsive, even when I just copy the snippet from semantic ui examples.

I used bower to install Semantic UI and Jquery to a separate bower_component directory which I then added as an additional content root to the project directory in phpstorm. I included semantic files in the html header as such and paths are all recognized:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/semantic_test.js"></script>
```

I copied the html from the first example [this link](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox.html#/examples) to the html  and the js to "js/semantic_test.js". The page is appearing static with all the styling correct but no response, in Chrome or Safari.

I tried some bootstrap components which functioned correctly. I have also tested CDN paths for both Jquery and Semantic UI - not working still. I have spent hours googling and would deeply appreciate some help please!

Comment: Have you [checked your console](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log) for errors?

Comment: I did and couldn't generate any response at all..but I tried what @albertlockett suggested below and it is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you wrap your jquery code in `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // your code here
 // ...
});
```

Sometimes this can happen when the script to initialize your html components with JavaScript runs before the components are loaded into the dom.

Comment: That must be it! It is working now - how basic indeed haha. Thank you :) !

Comment: Hey if this worked for you can you mark this as answered?